# Feynman parameters for $n=3$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, feynman-diagrams, integration

I proved the general formula for the Feynman parameters:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{P_1^{a_1}...P_n^{a_n}}=\frac{\Gamma(a_1+...+a_n)}{\Gamma(a_1)...\Gamma(a_n)}\int_0^1dx_1...dx_n\delta(1-x_1-...-x_n)\frac{x_1^{a_1-1}...x_n^{a_n-1}}{(x_1P_1+...+x_nP_n)^{a_1+...+a_n}},
\end{equation}
however in my lecture notes we used the special case:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{P_1^{a_1}P_2^{a_2}P_3^{a_3}}=\frac{\Gamma(a_1+a_2+a_3)}{\Gamma(a_1)\Gamma(a_2)\Gamma(a_3)}\int_0^1dx_1dx_2\frac{(x_1x_2)^{a_1-1}(x_1(1-x_2))^{a_2-1}(1-x_1)^{a_3-1}}{(x_1x_2P_1+x_1(1-x_2)P_2+(1-x_1)P_3))^{a_1+a_2+a_3}}
\end{equation}
that I don't know how to derive from the general formula.
I tried to perform the integration over $x_3$ from the general expression to get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{P_1^{a_1}P_2^{a_2}P_3^{a_3}}=\frac{\Gamma(a_1+a_2+a_3)}{\Gamma(a_1)\Gamma(a_2)\Gamma(a_3)} \int_0^1dx_1 \int_0^{1-x_1} dx_2\frac{x_1^{a_1-1}x_2^{a_2-1}(1-x_1-x_2)^{a_n-1}}{(x_1P_1+x_2P_2+(1-x_1-x_2)P_3)^{a_1+a_2+a_3}},
\end{equation}
but from here on I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Start with the general formula with $x_1,\ x_2,\ x_3$ and then let $x_3=1-y_1,\ x_1=y_1y_2,\ x_2=y_1y_3$, remembering to compute the Jacobian, and then integrate over $y_3$. If you can see what $y_3$ must be, then, of course, you can skip the integration and just write down the correct answer.